# AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'df2.*' give input columns Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created two data frames like below.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1, 2,4), (1, 2, 9,5), (2, 1, 2,1), (2, 2, 1,2), (4, 1, 5,2), (4, 2, 6,3), (5, 1, 3,3), (5, 2, 8,4)], 
   ("sid", "cid", "Cr","rank"))
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3], [2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3],[5,2],[5,3],[5,3],[3,4]],
    ["sid","cid"])
```

because of some requirement I had created sqlContext and created Temporary view,like below.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")

df2=sqlContext.sql("select sid,cid,cr,rank from temp")
```

then i am doing left join based on some condition .

```
joined = (df2.alias("df")
    .join(
        df1.alias("df1"),
        (col("df.sid") == col("df1.sid")) & (col("df.cid") == col("df1.cid")),
        "left"))
joined.show()

+---+---+---+----+----+----+
|sid|cid| cr|rank| sid| cid|
+---+---+---+----+----+----+
|  5|  1|  3|   3|null|null|
|  1|  1|  2|   4|   1|   1|
|  4|  2|  6|   3|   4|   2|
|  5|  2|  8|   4|   5|   2|
|  2|  2|  1|   2|   2|   2|
|  4|  1|  5|   2|   4|   1|
|  1|  2|  9|   5|   1|   2|
|  2|  1|  2|   1|   2|   1|
+---+---+---+----+----+----+
```

then finally i am executing below code:

```
final=joined.select(
    col("df2.*"),
    col("df1.sid").isNull().cast("integer").alias("flag")
).orderBy("sid", "cid")
```

then i am getting error like below.

```
"AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'df2.*' give input columns 'cr, sid, sid, cid, cid, rank';"
```

but my expected out put should be:

```
+---+---+---+----+----+
|sid|cid| Cr|rank|flag|
+---+---+---+----+----+
|  1|  1|  2|   4|   0|
|  1|  2|  9|   5|   0|
|  2|  1|  2|   1|   0|
|  2|  2|  1|   2|   0|
|  4|  1|  5|   2|   0|
|  4|  2|  6|   3|   0|
|  5|  1|  3|   3|   1|
|  5|  2|  8|   4|   0|
+---+---+---+----+----+
```

Comment: Just a mistake. You use `df` and `df1` as aliases, no `df2` :)

Comment: Hi ,Sorry  for type-o,now i want to use df2 only.

Answer (score 0):

mistake is :

```
joined = (df2.alias("df")
    .join(
        df1.alias("df1"),
        (col("df2.sid") == col("df1.sid")) & (col("df2.cid") == col("df1.cid")),
        "left"))
joined.show()
```

here we should to use `df2.alias("df2") or joined.select(col("df.*")..)`

Complete solution is :

```
joined = (df2.alias("df2")
    .join(
        df1.alias("df1"),
        (col("df2.sid") == col("df1.sid")) & (col("df2.cid") == col("df1.cid")),
        "left"))
joined.show()

final=joined.select(
    col("df2.*"),
    col("df1.sid").isNull().cast("integer").alias("flag")
).orderBy("sid", "cid")
```